# Weird behavior of Marshal when changing struct to list of bytes and back

Tags: c#, marshalling, unmarshalling

I've been trying to translate an struct to a series of bytes. He's my test struct:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Foo
{
    public int TestInt;

    public string Message;
}
```

I'm pushing it through method to get list of bytes:

```cs
public List<byte> Bytes;
public void PushBytesToList(Foo item)
{
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(item);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(item, ptr, false);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, buffer, 0, size);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

    Bytes.AddRange(buffer);
}
```

And from achieved bytes list i create Foo struct:

```cs
public static Foo Recreate(byte[] data)
{
    Foo result = default;
    GCHandle handle = default;

    try
    {
        handle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        result = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Foo>(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
        return result;
    }
    finally
    {
        if(handle.IsAllocated)
        {
            handle.Free();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested using Foo instance with TestInt = int.MaxValue and Message = "abc" and when I inspected that list of bytes TestInt was reasonably `255 255 255 127 0 0 0 0`, but Message's bytes was different with every run yet it always managed to get "abc" correctly.

Examples of Message bytes:

- `96 163 37 239 203 1 0 0`
- `96 28 239 229 47 2 0 0`
- `192 90 88 45 230 1 0 0`

I've got two questions:

- What's going on with that weird behavior of marshaler?
- Why for int there is 8 bytes instead of 4? When i tried to explicitly change offset of Message it was throwing exception that it overlaps.

Comment: `int` is 32bit for .Net, you may check it on [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types).

Comment: @LouisGo It's 32 bit, therefore 4 bytes. Why is there an extra 4?

Comment: If your platform is 64bit, then alignment is 8 bytes. But I don't get what you want to achieve at the moment, if you have unmanaged struct need to align with, then post your unmanaged structure. Because `Marshal` is used for creating memory to let unmanaged code use.

Comment: @LouisGo Oh, right, thanks for an answer to one of questions. I've just wanted to serialize (not sure if it's the best word here) an struct to byte[] for my networking to send it.

Comment: You probably don't want to serialise structs this way. Also, string is an object, only a pointer to the string instance will be stored inside the struct. If you don't want to write each serialisation method, IMHO use reflection to build an `Expression<Action<>>` then compile it.

Comment: If you need it to send by packet, [Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/) should be better than Marshal. I'd suggest json or xml serialization rather than binary serialization. Binary way has zero version compatible ability.